# jQuery UI - Create menu on click

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

I want to make a simple menu using jQuery UI depending on the position of the cursor. This is EXACTLY what I want: http://medialize.github.io/jQuery-contextMenu/demo/dynamic-create.html but as I said, I want to use jQuery UI. In the example http://jqueryui.com/menu/ the menu is always static on the screen, how can I make it dinamically (shows up near mouse click)?

Thanks in advance,

Lucas.

Comment: Bind a click event, determine when the user right clicks, get the offsets (both x, y), absolutely position your menu container based on those offsets. Show the menu. Voilà! You're done :)

Comment: yeah ok.. looking at the docs I could find something helpful https://api.jqueryui.com/position/ . Imma try it out

Comment: Cool! If you need help, I'll throw together a quick fiddle later tonight.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's the fiddle that I threw together.

http://jsfiddle.net/uG2EE/

It's not perfect by any means, but it does what you want (uses jQuery UI, shows up near cursor when the context menu event is fired - or right click)

Unfortunately, I had to paste jQuery UI script into the script pane, so you need to scroll to the very bottom. Here's the JS I added to get this working:

```
$(function() {
    // Set initial state (isVisible) then initialize menu
    $("#menu").data('isVisible', false).menu();

    // Initialize event handlers
    $(document).on({
        // Click is responsible for closing the menu, when it is visible
        'click': function(e){
            if(e.which === 1 && $('#menu').data('isVisible')){
                $("#menu").css({
                'display' : 'none'
                }).data('isVisible', false);
            }
        },
        // "onContextMenu" event is fired when user right clicks. We prevent the
        // default by calling e.preventDefault(), and then display our jQuery-UI menu
        'contextmenu': function(e){
            var x = e.clientX,
                y = e.clientY;

            e.preventDefault();

            // Check state (isVisible) to see if menu needs to be displayed
            if($('#menu').data('isVisible') === false) {
                $("#menu").css({
                'display' : 'block',
                'left' : x + 10,
                'top' : y + 10
                }).data('isVisible', true);
            }
        }
    });
});
```

The CSS is very straight forward: `display:none`, `position:absolute`, and the width.

Good luck!